# in SpringMVC getMessage from i18n properties in a function outside the controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, internationalization

I want to retrieve a message from i18n properties in a function. I can retrieve the message in my service layer or controller by this statement :

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext appContext;


public void myFunction(){
String errrorMsg = appContext.getMessage("application.errorcode.sessionExpiry", null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
}
```

But i want to retrieve this i18n message in a function which is outside the service layer or controller. This function is being called from my service layer.
How do i do it?
I have tried to copy the same code in the external class but I am getting nullPointerException

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inject the `MessageSource` into your service (instead of `ApplicationContext`).

Within that service you could than use `messageSource..getMessage("application.errorcode.sessionExpiry", null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());`

If you need this functionality outside this service (in some Not-Spring-Bean instance), then I would pass the `MessageSource` (and the locale) to this other class.

```
@Component
public class MessageSourceExternalizer {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    public String getMessage(String code) {
        //Attention LocaleContextHolder.getLocale() is thread based,
        //maybe you need some fallback locale
        return messageSource.getMessage(code, new Object[0], LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
    } }

@Service
public YourService {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSourceExternalizer messageSourceExternalizer;

    public void yourServiceMethod() {
        ....
        YourNotSpringBean yourNotSpringBean 
             = new YourNotSpringBean(messageSourceExternalizer);
        yourNotSpringBean.doSomething(...);
    } }


public class YourNotSpringBean {

    private final MessageSourceExternalizer messageSourceExternalizer;
    public YourNotSpringBean(MessageSourceExternalizer messageSourceExternalizer) {
         this.messageSourceExternalizer = messageSourceExternalizer;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        ....
        this.messageSourceExternalizer.getMessage("application.errorcode.sessionExpiry");
    }

}
```